# add_action funcionamento

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo alguns testes com o `wp_head()` de um tema do WordPress, o mesmo usa um esquema de ganchos com o `add_action`, eu acredito que entendi como ele funciona, o primeiro parâmetro é a função principal `wp_head` e o segundo é o nome da função onde estou chamando exemplo `do_active_header`.

O que acontece é que por padrão esse tema importa muitos arquivos desnecessários o que torna muito lento o carregamento da minha página. Minha dúvida e se eu posso fazer um `add_action` mais de uma vez para a mesma função, como aqui por exemplo:

```
function do_activate_header() {
    /**
     * Fires before the Site Activation page is loaded.
     *
     * Fires on the {@see 'wp_head'} action.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'activate_wp_head' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'do_activate_header' );
add_action( 'wp_head_teste', 'do_activate_header' );
```

Quero fazer dessa forma para entender exatamente quais arquivos eu preciso importar e quais eu posso remover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, pode fazer assim... pode também usar o remove_action, para remover o action do tema padrão

**remover o action que adiciona os scripts**

```php
# exemplo
function theme_name_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( '$handle', '$src', array( 'jquery' ), false, false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

# removendo action acima 
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```